# how do i get one sentence per paragraph (the sentence taken randomly)

Tags: java, string, random

i have 3 paragraphs and i try to get one sentence per paragraph. but, the sentences taken randomly.

beside that, it performed a total of 2 times iteration.

example :

```
String sentences = "i love u. i like u. i get money. \nOther side. 
A new car. white paint. \nSomething else. i see the sky.
i took a money yesterday. ";
```

there are 3 paragraphs and 9 sentences. I want to get output like this :

output :

(P : Paragraph, S = Sentence)

First iteration :

```
P0S1 : i like you
P1S0 : Other side
P2S1 : i see the sky
```

second iteration :

```
P0S2 : i get money
P1S2 : white paint
P2S0 : Something else
```

the sentence above is get by randomly

i have tried to pair the key and its sentence, but don't how to get the sentence randomly

my code :

```
Map<String,String> mapIndeksKeyAndSentence = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();

String sentences = "i love u. i like u. i get money. \nOther side. 
A new car. white paint. \nSomething else. i see the sky.
i took a money yesterday. ";

String [] arrSentence = sentence.split("\n");
for(int i=0; i<arrSentence.length; i++){

String[] arrSentenceByDot = arrSentence[i].split("\\. ");
for(int j=0; j<arrSentenceByDot.length; j++){

mapIndeksKeyAndSentence.put(i+""+j, arrSentenceByDot[j]);
}
}
```

and the ouput of mapIndeksKeyAndSentence is ::

```
the index : 00   //means = paragraph one, sentence one 
the sentence : i love you
.
.
.
etc . .
```

so, how do i get the sentence randomly with two iterations?.. help, please.

Comment: See [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) or [Math.random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random())

Comment: You can use (Math.random() * 3), in order to generate an int between 0 and 3.

Comment: unclearly :: what the meaning of number 3 ini  (Math.random() * 3)? is that the sum of iteration?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a list of all possible indices and suffle it using `Collections.suffle(...)`. Something like this:

```
import java.util.Collections;

...
...

List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<>(arrSentenceByDot.length);

for(int j=0; j<arrSentenceByDot.length; j++){
    indices.add(j);
}

Collections.shuffle(indices);

for(int j=0; j<indices.size(); j++){
    int index = indices.get(j);
    mapIndeksKeyAndSentence.put(i+""+index, arrSentenceByDot[index]);
}
```

Comment: it doens't show the number of paragraph and sentence like i needed.
beside that, i need more that one iteration (atleast two)

Comment: It should display the paragraph and sentence just like your code does. I do not understand what you mean by two iterations.

Comment: two iteration means :

there are 3 paragraph , get one sentence per paragraph by random

the output :
firt iteration :
`P0S1 : i like you
P1S0 : Other side
P2S1 : i see the sky`

second iteration :
`P0S2 : i get money
P1S2 : white paint
P2S0 : Something else`

like i describe above in my question

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sentences = "i love u. i like u. i get money. \nOther side. A new car. white paint. \nSomething else. i see the sky. i took a money yesterday. ";
    List<String[]> paragraphs = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    for(String s : sentences.split("\n"))
        paragraphs.add(s.split("\\. "));

    int i = 0;
    for(String[] ss : paragraphs) 
        System.out.println("P" + i++ + "S" + getRandom(ss));        
}

public static String getRandom(String[] s) {
    int i = (int) (Math.random() * s.length);
    return s[i];
}
```

Comment: it's ok. but, your output doesn't show the number of sentence. it just show the number of paragraph.

beside that. it only one iteration. and my problem need more than one (atleast two)